# Live audio format

Tags: iphone, audio, format

Are there any different formats for **live audio** in iPhone?

Thank You

Comment: "Will there be..." could actually be in a distant future?

Comment: I meant.. are there any seperate formats for live audio other than normal audio formats like AAC, ALAC, MP3, Linear PCM, HE-AAC, AMR etc in iPhone audio system

Answer (score 1):

Specifications taken from the official [iPhone website](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html):

> Audio formats supported: AAC (8 to 320
>   Kbps), Protected AAC (from iTunes
>   Store), HE-AAC, MP3 (8 to 320 Kbps),
>   MP3 VBR, Audible (formats 2, 3, 4,
>   Audible Enhanced Audio, AAX, and
>   AAX+), Apple Lossless, AIFF, and WAV

Answer (score 0):

You should go with AAC in a mp4-container, because mp4 is a good container for streaming media and the AAC-codec produces really good audio quality with a low bandwith.

And there are lot of streaming servers for this combination.